# Appliying an accent color to an particular EditText while others are unaffected

Tags: android, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I have a situtation where half of the activity has a background color similar to the ActionBar. Hence the EditText displayed in the region with the background should have a white accent color and the ones in the remaining region should have a the color of the ActionBar.

[Plan A]

I am using appcompat-v7 and managed to get the accent colors to all the EditText with `<item name="colorAccent">@color/createTaskPrimaryActionBar</item>` in the theme I have used for the activity. But this sets the color of all the edit texts to `@color/createTaskPrimaryActionBar`.

Is there a way to set individual colors to individual EditText ?

[Plan B]

My next best hope is *setting up an ActionBar with custom layout with an EditText in it* and I think that will complicate things. Also I'm not even sure if that is a good practice.

My hope is if I am using a darkaction bar shouldn't the accent color be light by default.

Have anybody tried Plan B, I dont want to invest more time in it if it's not worth it..

Answer (score 2):

For your Plan A.

It is possible set individual colors to individual EditText

```
youreditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above line of code did not bring out any change in my output.

Comment: SRC_IN works for me but it will color even the default grey state.

Comment: and setColorFilter does not affect RippleDrawable :(

Comment: There's a bug report http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22361 and says it doesnt work with hardware acceleration.